# Error inflating class <unknown> on second running of app

Tags: java, android, xml, mopub

I have a multi-activity app that is already on the market and is generally working fine. Just recently I have been modifying the code to process my (mopub) adverts in a different way. This seems to work fine when I run the program and play through multiple levels. The ads are appearing exactly when and where I want them. The problem comes after I quit the program and then try and start it again. My program's first activity is a "splash screen". On the second run I get the following error:

```
04-23 11:16:50.374: W/dalvikvm(10512): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.mygame/com.mycompany.mygame.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 11:16:50.394: E/AndroidRuntime(10512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
```

Any idea what could cause this - and why it didn't complain on the first run?

**EDIT:**

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Blah blah blah"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView                            <<== THIS IS LINE 24
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mygame_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="   My company name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** In response to a comment...

I have an application class defined as:

```
public class Globals extends Application
{
}
```

In its onCreate method I have...

```
    allocate_and_initialise_fresh_new_mAdView();
    load_mopub_banner_ad();
```

which are defined as...

```
void allocate_and_initialise_fresh_new_mAdView()
{
    mAdView = new MoPubView(this);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSBFNpdGUYkaoMDA");// PUB_ID_320x50
}

void load_mopub_banner_ad()
{
    if (mAdView != null)
    {
        mAdView.loadAd();
    }
    debug("Completed loadAd");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have an Idea..! Are you using any custom class in your layout file?

Comment: I don't think so - I presume you mean custom kinds of views. But I am creating and initialising a custom view which I create programatically within Splash.

Comment: android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  
what it is for?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a View in the Application class!

This is inadvisable and may mess things up. The context of a view should be the Activity that encompasses its lifetime. That is what the os expects from you.

Just remove it from the Application class and these errors will not re-appear.

Comment: I do not think that you should worry about loading of ads. You are getting paid anyways. For now, remove them from Application and tell me if the error persists. We will find a solution for the loading thing

Comment: Just shifted all the code exclusively into a single activity and got exactly the same error.

Comment: have you tried this on emulator? and still getting the error?
try it on different versions. But before this, remove the adview code and check if error still shows up

Comment: Without the ads the error does not appear. The add did not appear on the emulator.